# Reading text file to throw into an array

Tags: c#, string, for-loop

I am trying to read a text file and throw data into a string array. I need this to read the text file and split after every ','. After which, be able to through that data (that precedes from the comma) into an other string array. I've tried this, but I get an error "cannot implicitly convert string[] to string. I think it has to do with my split method.

Here's my code:

```
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("../../Privileges.txt");

            string[] names;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                names[i] = lines[i].Split(',');
            }
```

So an example to help further understanding. A .txt file that reads

Joe Dirt, Optimus Prime, Jake the Snake

The out come I'm trying to produce is this:

```
names[0] = Joe Dirt
names[1] = Optimus Prime
names[2] = Jake the Snake
```

Cheers

Comment: `names` is an array of strings. Based on what you're doing now, you need it to be an *array of arrays of strings*.

Comment: One line solution: `string[] names = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("../../Privileges.txt").Trim(), @"\r\n|,\s*");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try to assign an array of strings to a string (the split function is returning an array of strings)

you can create a jagged array of array of strings which allow you to index them as `names[row][col]` or to access a whole line (as array) as `names[row]`

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("../../Privileges.txt");

string[][] names = new string[lines.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    names[i] = lines[i].Split(',');
}
```

to generate the desired output you can join the parts together:

```
foreach (string[] parts in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", parts));
}
```

in case you dont care on which line the names are, you just want **a list of all names in the file** you can do it with LINQ:

```
string[] names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("../../Privileges.txt")
  .SelectMany((line) => line.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

EDIT:
to read the names on a specific line you can use following function:

```
public static string[] GetNamesOnLine(int lineIndex, string filename)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    if (lineIndex >= lines.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Line {0} does not exist in file. File contains only {1} rows", lineIndex, lines.Length));

    return lines[lineIndex].Split(',');
}
```

but thats not very efficient as it reads the whole file even if you just want the names in the first line

Comment: Would there be a way to read a specific line in the .txt file, say for example I just want to read the names on line 2. Good answer though, I am using the linq expression, is there a way we can modify it just to read one specific line? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The `Split()` method return a `string[]`, and you are assigning it to a `string` (`names[i]`)

Since there can be **many names in one line** (as I suspect), you should do this:

```
List<string> nameList = new ArrayList<string>();
foreach(string line in lines)
    string[] namesLine = line.Split(',');
    foreach(string name in namesLine)
        nameList.Add(name);
```

If you would like to have `nameList` as a `string[]`, you can do:

```
string[] names = nameList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("../../Privileges.txt");

 string[][] names;
 for(int i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
     names[i] = lines[i].Split(',');
```

Comment: He doesn't want to end up with a two dimension array, you should convert it to one dimension

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare a multidimensional array for your names variable because it needs to store different arrays for each line of the txt file

`string[][] names = new string[lines.Count()][];`

Answer (score -2):

try this one :

```
string[] names = File.ReadAllText("../../Privileges.txt").Split(',');
```